# User input database with structure needs to find class average

Tags: c, arrays, database, structure

Alright so I've having trouble on the next step of my c program. Basically, it is a database that accepts user input and then uses a switch-statement to retrieve or calculate the individual or group statistics. Note that:
A student whose EUID (roll number) is stored in location i of the EUID array will have his or her homework average, exam 1 grade, and exam 2 grade stored in location i of the appropriate arrays.

So far the code is able to run but I'm stumped when it comes to the switch statement.

I only really need advice on the first case of the switch statement but included the rest just in case.

In short for case 1, how can I get the program to print out a student's grades and average using a specific EUID. The output should look something like this:

> 1
>
> Please enter student EUID: 
>   1893839
>
> EUID: 1893839 Homework: 84.34 Exam 1: 84 Exam 2: 76

Here's what I have so far:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


struct Grade
{
   int euid;
   double hwavg;
   double exam1;
   double exam2;

};


int main()

{
    struct Grade record[200];

    int input, i;

    printf("Input each student's EUID, homework average, exam 1 grade, and exam 2 grade: \n\n");

    printf("To terminate input '-1' as the student EUID, along with throwaway values for the average and grades.");

    for(i=0; i<200; ++i)
    {

        scanf("%d %lf %lf %lf", &record[i].euid, &record[i].hwavg, &record[i].exam1, &record[i].exam2);

        if(record[i].euid == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    while(1)
    {

        printf("Select one of the following:\n 1. Student grade data \n 2. Student grade average \n 3. Class average for assignment \n 4. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d\n",&input);

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:

                printf("Enter the student's EUID:\n");
                   /*The output here should be the EUID, homework avgerage, exam 1 grade and exam 2 grade. */ 


                break;

            case 2:

                printf("Enter the student's EUID:\n");   
                   /*Finds and prints the the students average and letter grade. */

                   /* (HW * 0.5) + (EXAM1 * 0.25) + (EXAM2 * 0.25) */  


                break;

            case 3:
                   /* Finds total class average. */ 
                break:

            case 4:

                printf("Terminating program: Bye-bye!\n");
                return 0;
                break;

            default:

                printf("Error! Invalid input.\n\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like `C` instead of `C#`.

Comment: Woops! Sorry about that.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How can I get the program to print out a student's grades and average using a specific EUID. The output should look something like this:
Please enter student EUID: 1893839
EUID: 1893839
Homework: 84.34
Exam 1: 84
Exam 2: 76

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it seems what you're looking for is something along the line...

```
printf("EUID:%d  Homework:  %.2f  Exam 1:%.0f  Exam2:  %.0f\n", record[i].euid, record[i].hwavg, record[i].exam1, record[1].exam2);
```

Note: The %.0f makes an output of 0 decimals.

In order to calculate the average, this can be done in your first for-loop, which reads and fills in the array.

You may want to search the net for "printf double"; [here's an example reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).
-What I almost never see mentioned is that you can choose argument numbers using %2$f (where 2 denotes argument number 2).

To find the index of the EUID, you could use something like this:

```
i = 0;
while(record[i].euid != -1 && record[i].euid != euid)
{
    i++;
}
```

-You'll of course need to scanf to get the euid.

Comment: Sorry about the %u; I just noticed this was a signed integer, not unsigned.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the right output almost but instead of the requested EUID information, it displays the '-1' values that were supposed end the for-loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure. You'll need to search the array for the entered EUID and set i to the resulting index. ;)